# extracting data from php SESSION var

Tags: php, json, session

I have a rather complex SESSION data set up in my code.. it contains variables and json data.   What I would like to know is how to output a specific entry  "name".  It should return "John Smith" but currently it is returning nothing

ps. I should have said, this is NOT my code, its a wordpress plugin and I just want to pull the data they have provided in the SESSION var.

I've tried

```
print_r($_SESSION['asp_data']->source->name);
print_r($_SESSION['asp_data']['source']->name);
print_r($_SESSION['asp_data']['source']['name'];
```

and other variations of the above..

here's a var_dump of _SESSION

```
Array ( [asp_data] => Array ( [product_id] => 73134 [is_live] => 0 [item_name] => IQ Test [stripeToken] => tok_1D42CiLqRQ0yhU0NoaKBXisf [stripeTokenType] => card [stripeEmail] => spam@spammer.com [item_quantity] => 1 [item_price] => 19.99 [discount_item_price] => 19.99 [paid_amount] => 19.99 [amount_in_cents] => 1999 [currency_code] => USD [charge_description] => 1 X $19.99 [addonName] => [button_key] => [charge] => Stripe\Charge JSON: { "id": "ch_1D42CmLqRQ0yhU0NT3f0Zr4N", "object": "charge", "amount": 1999, "amount_refunded": 0, "application": null, "application_fee": null, "balance_transaction": "txn_1D42CmLqRQ0yhU0NHwqH2M9Y", "captured": true, "created": 1535443540, "currency": "usd", "customer": null, "description": "1 X $19.99", "destination": null, "dispute": null, "failure_code": null, "failure_message": null, "fraud_details": [], "invoice": null, "livemode": false, "metadata": [], "on_behalf_of": null, "order": null, "outcome": { "network_status": "approved_by_network", "reason": null, "risk_level": "normal", "seller_message": "Payment complete.", "type": "authorized" }, "paid": true, "receipt_email": "spam@spammer.com", "receipt_number": null, "refunded": false, "refunds": { "object": "list", "data": [], "has_more": false, "total_count": 0, "url": "\/v1\/charges\/ch_1D42CmLqRQ0yhU0NT3f0Zr4N\/refunds" }, "review": null, "shipping": null, "source": { "id": "card_1D42CiLqRQ0yhU0NeYtNArFt", "object": "card", "address_city": "London", "address_country": "United Kingdom", "address_line1": "Whitacres Road", "address_line1_check": "pass", "address_line2": null, "address_state": "SCT", "address_zip": "NW1 4DJ", "address_zip_check": "pass", "brand": "Visa", "country": "US", "customer": null, "cvc_check": "pass", "dynamic_last4": null, "exp_month": 2, "exp_year": 2022, "fingerprint": "AROHy31e67u0TucD", "funding": "credit", "last4": "4242", "metadata": [], "name": "John Smith", "tokenization_method": null }, "source_transfer": null, "statement_descriptor": null, "status": "succeeded", "transfer_group": null } [txn_id] => ch_1D42CmLqRQ0yhU0NT3f0Zr4N [billing_address] => John Smith Whitacres Road NW1 4DJ London SCT United Kingdom [shipping_address] => [additional_items] => Array ( ) [order_post_id] => 73150 [item_url] => [charge_date_raw] => 1535443540 [charge_date] => 2018/08/28 08:05:40 ) [score] => 91 )
```

here's the output of  FOR EACH on _SESSION variable -

```
product_id 73134
is_live 0
item_name IQ Test
stripeToken tok_1D42CiLqRQ0yhU0NoaKBXisf
stripeTokenType card
stripeEmail spam@spammer.com
item_quantity 1
item_price 19.99
discount_item_price 19.99
paid_amount 19.99
amount_in_cents 1999
currency_code USD
charge_description 1 X $19.99
addonName 
button_key 
charge Stripe\Charge JSON: { "id": "ch_1D42CmLqRQ0yhU0NT3f0Zr4N", "object": 
"charge", "amount": 1999, "amount_refunded": 0, "application": null, 
"application_fee": null, "balance_transaction": 
"txn_1D42CmLqRQ0yhU0NHwqH2M9Y", "captured": true, "created": 1535443540, 
"currency": "usd", "customer": null, "description": "1 X $19.99", 
"destination": null, "dispute": null, "failure_code": null, 
"failure_message": null, "fraud_details": [], "invoice": null, "livemode": 
false, "metadata": [], "on_behalf_of": null, "order": null, "outcome": { 
"network_status": "approved_by_network", "reason": null, "risk_level": 
"normal", "seller_message": "Payment complete.", "type": "authorized" }, 
"paid": true, "receipt_email": "spam@spammer.com", "receipt_number": null, 
"refunded": false, "refunds": { "object": "list", "data": [], "has_more": 
false, "total_count": 0, "url": 
"\/v1\/charges\/ch_1D42CmLqRQ0yhU0NT3f0Zr4N\/refunds" }, "review": null, 
"shipping": null, "source": { "id": "card_1D42CiLqRQ0yhU0NeYtNArFt", 
"object": "card", "address_city": "London", "address_country": "United 
Kingdom", "address_line1": "Whitacres Road", "address_line1_check": "pass", 
"address_line2": null, "address_state": "SCT", "address_zip": "NW1 4DJ", 
"address_zip_check": "pass", "brand": "Visa", "country": "US", "customer": 
null, "cvc_check": "pass", "dynamic_last4": null, "exp_month": 2, 
"exp_year": 2022, "fingerprint": "AROHy31e67u0TucD", "funding": "credit", 
"last4": "4242", "metadata": [], "name": "John Smith", 
"tokenization_method": null }, "source_transfer": null, 
"statement_descriptor": null, "status": "succeeded", "transfer_group": null 
}
txn_id ch_1D42CmLqRQ0yhU0NT3f0Zr4N
billing_address John Smith Whitacres Road NW1 4DJ London SCT United Kingdom 
shipping_address 
additional_items Array
order_post_id 73150
item_url 
charge_date_raw 1535443540
charge_date 2018/08/28 08:05:40
```

Comment: A free hint: do not store json and everything into the session, rather store a reference to the database where you have all the related data

Comment: `foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
    echo $key." ".$val."<br/>";` what does this print?

Comment: storing this amount of data in the session is probably a symptom of a design flaw in your application. Web apps should be largely stateless. Session data is generally just for things which might persist through the whole session such as the ID of the current user.

Comment: @Isaac I've updated the question with the results of a FOR EACH

Comment: store value of charge in json_decode($charge,true) ; that way you will get JSON data in a PHP Array , and then you can traverse it

Comment: If your session data is more complex then you can make it simple during session value assignments(initial stage). create it in the way so that you can easily extracts the value per your need.

Comment: ps. I should have said, this is NOT my code, its a wordpress plugin and I just want to pull the data they have provided in the SESSION var.

Comment: what is the name of the plugin?

Comment: @vanurag "Stripe Payments"

Comment: Okay so as I am understanding that this session values are after after payment data?

Comment: @vanurag correct !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the `json` object first before you can read it using php, something like:

```
// parse the json string value of the 'charge' key to make it a php array
$json = json_decode($_SESSION['asp_data']['charge'], true);
// echo the value of the 'name' key from the parsed json object
echo $json['source']['name'];
```

Comment: This still returns BLANK !

Comment: Maybe it's because the `charge` value is prepended with `Stripe\Charge JSON: `?
`$json = json_decode(ltrim($_SESSION['asp_data']['charge'], 'Stripe\Charge JSON: '), true);`